# How can I have multiple apache sites under the same domain?

Tags: server, apache2, configuration

I have a single IP that is external - say `xx.xx.xx.xx`. Currently, I have 2 urls that resolve to the IP address. I use virtual hosts within Apache to make sure that the right requests go to the site:

```
www.mysite1.com --> /home/mysite1
www.mysite2.com --> /home/mysite2
```

Works great. However ...

I want to add a 3rd (and then 4th and 5th, etc) site to this IP. The sites are temporary and thus won't get domain names. I was hoping to access them by using:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mysite3 where mysite3 --> /home/mysite3
```

but it seems that the virtual host from site1 catches these requests and routes the request to `www.mysite1.com` which struggles finding the files (mysite3) so I get the `www.mysite1.com` with 404 page (They are all Wordpress sites).

I am sure that this can be done but I am just as sure I can't figure it out.

Does anyone have an idea of how I need to configure "things"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You have 2 solutions

### 1. Creating a Virtual Host for each site

*In my opinion, I would recommend this solution if it's a possibility.*

In this step, you would need need to create a site just as you did for your previous ones. But you will need to give them a domain like `www.site3.temp` even if it won't have a dns record. **(notice the `.tmp` TLD)**

Next, for each user that will open that site, they would need to edit their hosts file and add a line which points that temp url to your IP. Like so:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx      www.site3.tmp
```

1. In Linux and Mac OS the hosts file is located at `/etc/hosts`
2. In Windows it's located in `<Windows Installation>/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`
   By default, `<Windows Installation>` is in `C:/Windows`

### 2. Creating an Alias

*If editing of the `hosts` file is not a solution, then this is you only other option*

This would require you to edit your default virtual host file. It's the virtual host of `www.mysite1.com`, since it's the one that is opening when you go to `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/mysite3`.
<sup>This is the reason I don't like this solution since it makes stuff ugly and cluttered. And I only use it as a last resort.</sup>

In the Virtual Host configuration, add the following line (Changing the paths as required of course):

```
Alias /mysite3 /home/mysite3/
# Notice that there isn't a trailing slash
# So this won't work: Alias /mysite3/ /home/mysite3/
```

Of course, if you need to add some apache configuration to the directory, the also need to be done in the same host file.

```
<Directory /home/site3/>
    AllowOverride All # Just an example
</Directory>
```

### 3. (Bonus) Combining both solution

*This is better then the second solution, but not as good as the first one*

The default Virtual Host file is the first one loaded by apache. And by default, apache loads them alphabetically. So, what you can do, you can create a new virtual host file which would precede all your other virtual hosts files.
For example, `000-default` (Which is now done in the default configuration of apache2.4).

Then create all your Aliases in that Host file, and the default URL of this virtual host would go to a 403 page. So in the end, you would get this:

```
www.mysite1.com   --> /home/mysite1
www.mysite2.com   --> /home/mysite2
xx.xx.xx.xx       --> 403 Error
xx.xx.xx.xx/site3 --> /home/site3
xx.xx.xx.xx/site4 --> /home/site4
```

This is preferred over the second solution, since that one might conflict with your other sites. For example, it might get messed up with your URL rewrites.

Comment: Used solution #1. Worked perfectly and saved me hours. Much thanks ...

Comment: Another way to go about this is to use the `~user` feature of Apache. Create a folder called `public_html` in the /home/user folder, and add files to that.

Comment: @FireFaced You are right! Though I don't recommend doing this on a live server, specially if you don't know what you are doing. You would need to enable the `userdir` module for apache; You should add that as answer by the way.